# Disable 'Return' key in a QPlainTextEdit

Tags: qt, pyqt4

Is there any way I can prevent the user from hitting the return key when entering text in a `QPlainTextEdit` widget? That is, even though I want to give the viewing space of multiple lines, I want that the if the user hits enter, a new line should not begin.

The reason for doing this is that I am adding a GUI layer on top of an existing command-line and if the user enters data using the return key, it might complicate stuff and I had really avoid changing the command line code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the key press event and filter out any return keys.
There isn't IIRC a 'allowed chars' validator for a qtextedit.

Although you can use [QValidator](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qvalidator.html#details) with a QLineEdit.
See this [example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/widgets-lineedits.html)

ps. If you also have to deal with pasting in text with a CR, then you need to deal with the textchanged signal as well

Comment: Right thanks for the `textchanged` thought, I had not taken into account the pasting text problem.